# MySQL limit relationship table with FIFO

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, fifo

Currently working on a MySQL structure for a social network site.

I have a requirement: a user can only have a maximum of 5 friends, and when adding a 6th it would remove the oldest one (FIFO), and I'm not entirely sure what is the best way to solve that.

In my backend code I also add a constraint when adding a user so that user1_id < user2_id.

Here is the relevant table:

```
CREATE TABLE friendships (
user1_id INT,
user2_id INT,
date_added DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FOREIGN KEY (user1_id)
    REFERENCES users (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (user2_id)
    REFERENCES users (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE UNIQUE index single on friendships (user1_id, user2_id);
```

I thought about using a trigger and wrote this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inFriendships 
BEFORE INSERT ON friendships
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE current_amount_user1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE current_amount_user2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  SET current_amount_user1 = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friendships WHERE (user1_id = NEW.user1_id OR user2_id = NEW.user1_id) );
  IF current_amount_user1 = 5
    THEN 
      DELETE FROM friendships WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL AND (user1_id = NEW.user1_id OR user2_id = NEW.user1_id) order by date_added desc LIMIT 1;
  END IF;
  SET current_amount_user2 = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friendships WHERE (user1_id = NEW.user2_id OR user2_id = NEW.user2_id) );
  IF current_amount_user2 = 5
    THEN 
      DELETE FROM friendships WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL AND (user1_id = NEW.user2_id OR user2_id = NEW.user2_id) order by date_added desc LIMIT 1;
  END IF;
END;
```

But I ran into an issue with dead locks and now I'm trying to find a different solution.

All solutions and ideas are welcome both SQL and backend psuedo code.

Answer (score 0):

`(user1_id = NEW.user2_id OR user2_id = NEW.user2_id)` would mean a user can only be associated with at most 5 persons. There should be a sense; `user1_id` should be the id of the parent user, and `user2_id` should be the children user.
With this in mind to get the number of friends of a user do:

```
SELECT user1_id, user2_id, date_updated from friendships where user1_id=NEW.user1_id;
```

You can allow data insertion into friendships, then run a trigger after insert to remove the oldest friend if the number of friends is more than 5.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Can't update table 'friendships' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger''.